# Issue persisting dask dataframe from read_sql_table & understanding dask distributed Client.get_future_errors output

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

After setting up a cluster using the dask-ec2 script, I try to read a sql table as a dask dataframe. My query looks like:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client, progress
c = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')

df = dd.read_sql_table(sql_table_name, uri, index_col=column_1,  
columns=[column_2, column_3, column_4], npartitions=393, parse_dates=
[date_column_1, date_column_2])
```

Where sql_table_name and uri are strings specific to my database. I then try to persist the df using the dask.distributed client:

```
df = c.persist(df)
progress(df)
```

The progress bar shows an exception at 0.6 seconds. I use c.get_futures_error(df) to try and understand why and return something like:

```
(<function distributed.worker.execute_task>,
  ((<function dask.compatibility.apply>,
   <function pandas.io.sql.read_sql>,
   [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x7fd5e3b0a4e0; Select object>,
*the uri I used*],
   (dict,
[['parse_dates',
  [date_column_1, date_column_2]],
 ['index_col', column_1]])),),
{},
[])
```

I would be grateful for any guidance on why I might be getting these futures errors and what I can do to mitigate them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for [Client.recreate_error_locally](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.recreate_exceptions.ReplayExceptionClient.recreate_error_locally)

```
>>> future = c.submit(div, 1, 0)         
>>> future.status                        
'error'
>>> c.recreate_error_locally(future)     
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I might have been getting an exception initially because I hadn't set the scheduler to distributed? But on a later exception, running future = c.persist(df) and then c.recreate_error_locally(future) returned 'ValueError: Metadata mismatch found in from_delayed.'